# Can someone make an example of how to check if email and password exists in database with PDO? (FOR DUMMIES).

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

Heres is all relevant code. What I want to do is sent some parameters to a php file using ajax, and check if they are in db. If not echo and error message and if they are echo success message. I don't know how to retrieve all result from the database and compare them with the ones I input. Thank you.

AJAX

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
  $("input[name=send_login]").click(function() {
         var value_email_login = $("#email_login").val() ;
         var value_password_login = $("#password_login").val() ;

         if(value_email_login == '' && value_password_login == ''){
             $(".info_message_login").show();
             $(".info_message_login").html("Campos Vacios");
         }else{
             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'php/login.php',
                 data: {email: value_email_login, password: value_password_login},
                 success: function(){
                     $(".info_message_login").show();
                     $(".info_message_login").text("Bienvenido...");
                 },
                 error: function(response){
                     $(".info_message_login").show();
                     $(".info_message_login").text(response.responseText);
                  },
             });
         }
   });
});
```

FORM

```
<form class="" action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email_login" placeholder="Email"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password_login" placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class=" btn btn-default " type="button" name="send_login" value="Send"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class=" btn btn-default " type="reset" name="reset_login" value="Reset"/>
    </div>
    <div class="info_message_login" style="display:none;">

    </div>
</form>
```

PHP FILE

```
 <?php
session_start();

require_once "db.php";

$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

$sql_login = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql_login);

$statement->bindValue(':email', $email);
$statement->bindValue(':password', $password);


$statement->execute()
```

Comment: So ? Did you get how does it work

Comment: well, don't really :( @xNeyte

Comment: Wrote you an example tho, what didn't you understand

Comment: i've found something like: 
`if ($statement->rowCount()>0 ) {
     echo("GOOD");
}else{
    echo("BAD");
}` 
but as I send the parameters through ajax I don't really know how to see where is my error.

Comment: fetch does the same thing, you can add 'data' to your success function : `function(data)` then `alert(data);` to see your error

Answer (score 0):

```
$statement = $connection->prepare(<<<SQL
    SELECT * 
    FROM users 
    WHERE email = :email 
    AND password = :password
SQL
);

$statement->execute(array(":email" => $email, 
                          ":password" => $password));

if($statement->fetch()) {
    $_SESSION['login'] = 'ok';
}
```

I let you hash passwords with sha1 or whatever you want